# how to create computational mesh of a geometry with known level set function definition of its boundary

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I have a level set function, that defines a "flower like" shape geometry. I want to create a 2D fitted computational mesh around this flower geometry (flower geometry inside a unit square) with a free meshing tool but no free tool seems to work with level set definitions. Anyone knows such meshing tool that I can use?

I have visitied FreeFem, ngsolve and fenicsproject tools but none was working to create a fitted mesh around a level set defined geometry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean an isosurface? (implicit surface)

Comment: yes thats what i tried to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot an isosurface, you can

- use Python with the **PyVista** library;
- use R with the **rmarchingcubes** and **rgl** libraries;
- use [CalcPlot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html) online (select "implicit surface").

All these ways produce an interactive graphic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not try any of those, probably they would work as well. Just to share information, I have compiled the developer version of FreeFem software which has a recently added mmg2d feature to do what I needed.